# Securing my php from injection

Tags: php, mysql, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

I know there's a lot of guides out there about this topic and I've read a lot about it but I wanted to ask someone directly and get confirmation about this.

Okay so to my questions. First of all, how often do you need to use mysql_real_escape_string.

Example, if I have a query with:

```
"SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE id = $_POST['id'] and email LIKE '%hotmail.com' and row = 2"
```

What exactly do I need to escape here? Is it enough with the $_POST or should I do it with all the variables in the query? `(saferize(2), saferize(%hotmail.com))`?

Another question I have is if this function is good for sanitizing?

```
function saferize($string) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true) { 
        $string = stripslashes($string);
    }
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
    if(strpos($string, '&lt;br /&gt;')){
        $string = str_replace('&lt;br /&gt;', '<br />', $string);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}
```

I am inserting `<br />` directly into the database so i made an exeption for the `htmlspecialchars($string)` for that purpose. Whats the security regard on this?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Use [Prepared Statements with PDO](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Comment: "How often do you need to use mysql_real_escape_string" — Never, because you shouldn't be building SQL by mashing strings together in the first place.

Comment: Many will yell at you: don't use `mysql_*` in new code, use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli objects, prepared statement, and data binding.

Answer (score 0):

if the $_POST['id'] is an integer, u can cast it explicitly to an integer and use the result in the query

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id']
"SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE id = $id and email LIKE '%hotmail.com' and row = 2"
```

or use a PDO prepared statement

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE id = ? and email LIKE '%hotmail.com' and row = 2");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['id']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
```